# Q: How to control theme colors for Drupal 7 mass contact email

Tags: theming, emails

I'm using the *Corporate Clean* theme as the basis for my site.  I've customized some theme colors to my liking.  I have installed the *Mass Contacts* module to send bulk email.  I've specified in the mail system configuration to use the *Corporate Clean* theme.  The customizations do not appear to cause the following problem since I can't see any color settings that reflect what I'm seeing with the problem.

**Problem:**

The email that is received (via Thunderbird) is displayed with a dark gray background and light gray lettering.  It is readable, although, I'd like to make it easier on the eyes.  On my phone, it is unreadable - the text actually shows as black text on a dark gray background.  I'm assuming that the color is specified somewhere in the theme or css.  However, I have not been able to locate the settings that would allow me to change the color combinations.  I've read a [similar, but, old post](https://www.drupal.org/node/121849) but did not quite understand if there was a solution mentioned.

I'd like to get a better understanding of how to control the theme colors for email.  Can anyone tell me how the colors are controlled and how I can change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading the post I mentioned several times, I found one of the comments to actually be the answer to my problem.  That post, created by dwils03, indicated:

> In case anyone was looking for a quick and dirty fix, I just included
>   a blank mail.css file in my theme's folder. The result is an
>   html-formatted, NON-STYLED email.

I did the same and added an **empty** mail.css file in my theme folder and it solved my problem.